# Why scope model is not updated?

Tags: angularjs

In controller `CommentController` I have scope: `$scope.comment = {file : {}};`

In template there is code:

```
<form ng-controller="CommentController" class="form-horizontal" name="formComment" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
<textarea ng-model="comment.body" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="500" class="form-control todo-taskbody-taskdesc" rows="4" placeholder="Type comment..." required autofocus></textarea>

<input type="text" ng-model="comment.file" ng-value="f | ngfDataUrl" ng-repeat="f in files">

</form>
```

If to make {{comment}} in tempate I can see binding `comment.body` when I typing text in textarea.

But I dont see values in:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="comment.file" ng-value="f | ngfDataUrl" ng-repeat="f in files">
```

But object `files` is not empty.

Input file is:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="comment.file[$index]" ng-value="f | ngfDataUrl" ng-repeat="f in files" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-empty ng-touched" value="blob:http://bg.com/ec70ef5e-0971-4cb5-b7c0-6032413c4bee">
```

Comment: show your `$scope.comment` object properly and what is the reason behind `ng-repeat="f in files"`

Comment: After submit `$scope.comment` is: `Object {file: Object, body: "dgdgdgdgdg"}`

Comment: if file is a object then why you made it `ng-model` for input field

Comment: Because I use another library that forms object `files`. After I try to get thi in input hidden

Comment: create a plunk for this for better understanding .  https://plnkr.co